# C# UWP More information about Methods Implemetation from Microsoft

Tags: c#, uwp, libraries

Is there a way to see how Microsoft .NET methods are implemented (*e.g.* what happened in .NET Core) or is it a blackbox?
Or are there any links to get a better understand on how these methods works, not just seeing the return of the methods?
For example the [`RecognizeAsync` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.speechrecognition.speechrecognitionresult)  in SpeechRecognitionResult class.

Comment: use dotnet peek to decompile code.

Comment: A lot of it is available in the [Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/) or the [GitHub repo for .NET](https://github.com/dotnet)

Answer (score 1):

.Net Core itself is open source. The method you're taking about is not actually .Net Core but a UWP SDK method, which more often that not is implemented in C++/COM and is most definitely not open source. Outside of reading the documentation, understanding the method internal workings is going to be very difficult.